# I can't get a JavaScript location to be returned

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I am part of a team for a competition, and we are trying to get the users location, and from that output, if their location is good for a certain energy source. All I really need is a way to either:

1. set their latitude and longitude as two separate global (I believe that's the correct term) variables, or
2. create two methods, one that returns the users latitude when called and one that returns their longitude

I am still fairly new to JavaScript, and any help with my issue, or any other issues I have missed, or even better programming habits that I am doing wrong, would be helpful. I will include all the code so you can see what I am going for, but I think only two of the methods need some work. Thanks so much.

P.S. If something is wrong with my post, I'm sorry, it's my first time posting to a forum.

```
var userLocation=document.getElementById("location");
var latitude1;
var longitude1;

//Program gets user location and divides US into 32 sections, and based on the location sets and outputs if the specefic energy type is good for the users location

window.onload = function () {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        setLat()
        setLon()
        displayEnergy()
    }
    else
        userLocation.innerHTML = "GeoLocation is not supported by this browser";
}

function setLat() {
    function displayLocation(position) {
        latitude1 = position.coords.latitude;
    }

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation);
}

function setLon() {
    function displayLocation(position) {
        longitude1 = position.coords.longitude;
    }

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation);
}

function getSection() {
    var lat, lon;

    if (longitude1<=-65&&longitude1>-75)
        lat="a";
    else if (longitude1<=-75&&longitude1>-85)
        lat="b";
    else if (longitude1<=-85&&longitude1>-95)
        lat="c";
    else if (longitude1<=-95&&longitude1>-105)
        lat="d";
    else if (longitude1<=-105&&longitude1>-115)
        lat="e";
    else if (longitude1<=-115&&longitude1>-125)
        lat="f";

    if (latitude1>=25&&latitude1<30)
        lon="a";
    else if (latitude1>=30&&latitude1<35)
        lon="b";
    else if (latitude1>=35&&latitude1<40)
        lon="c";
    else if (latitude1>=40&&latitude1<45)
        lon="d";
    else if (latitude1>=45&&latitude1<50)
        lon="e";

    //Alaska and Hawaii
    else if (latitude1>=50&&latitude1<75&&longitude1<=-140&&longitude1>-170){
        lat="g";
        lon="g";
    }
    else if(latitude1>=10&&latitude1<30&&longitude1<=-150&&longitude1>-165){
        lat="h";
        lon="h";
    }

    var section=lon+lat;

    return section;
}

function pageIs() {
    //What energy is the current page displaying, utilizes empty div on each page
    var page;

    if (document.getElementById("pageSolar"))
        page="solar";
    else if(document.getElementById("pageWind"))
        page="wind";
    else if(document.getElementById("pageGeo"))
        page="geo";
    else if(document.getElementById("pageHydro"))
        page="hydro";

    return page;
}

function displayEnergy() {
    var solarE, windE, geoE, hydroE;
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //Is solar energy a good choice
    if (getSection()=="ba" ||
        getSection()=="bb" ||
        getSection()=="bc" ||
        getSection()=="ca" ||
        getSection()=="cb" ||
        getSection()=="cc" ||
        getSection()=="da" ||
        getSection()=="db" ||
        getSection()=="dc" ||
        getSection()=="dd" ||
        getSection()=="eb" ||
        getSection()=="ec" ||
        getSection()=="fb" ||
        getSection()=="fc" ||
        getSection()=="hh")

        solarE=true;
    else
        solarE=false;

    //Is wind energy a good choice
    if (getSection()=="ad" ||
        getSection()=="ba" ||
        getSection()=="bb" ||
        getSection()=="bd" ||
        getSection()=="cb" ||
        getSection()=="cd" ||
        getSection()=="ce" ||
        getSection()=="da" ||
        getSection()=="db" ||
        getSection()=="fb" ||
        getSection()=="fc" ||
        getSection()=="fd" ||
        getSection()=="fe")

        windE=true;
    else
        windE=false;

    //Is geothermal energy a good choice
    if (getSection()=="db" ||
        getSection()=="dc" ||
        getSection()=="dd" ||
        getSection()=="de" ||
        getSection()=="eb" ||
        getSection()=="ed" ||
        getSection()=="ee" ||
        getSection()=="fb" ||
        getSection()=="fc" ||
        getSection()=="hh")

        geoE=true;
    else
        geoE=false;

    //Is hydroelectric energy a good choice
    if (getSection()=="ad" ||
        getSection()=="ba" ||
        getSection()=="bb" ||
        getSection()=="bc" ||
        getSection()=="bd" ||
        getSection()=="cb" ||
        getSection()=="cd" ||
        getSection()=="ce" ||
        getSection()=="da" ||
        getSection()=="ec" ||
        getSection()=="ed" ||
        getSection()=="fb" ||
        getSection()=="fc" ||
        getSection()=="fd" ||
        getSection()=="gg" ||
        getSection()=="hh")

        hydroE=true;
    else
        hydroE=false;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    if (pageIs()=="solar"&&solarE===true)
        userLocation.innerHTML="Based on your location, solar energy would be a good option";
    else if (pageIs()=="solar"&&solarE===false)
        userLocation.innerHTML="Based on your location, solar energy would not be a good option";
    else if (pageIs()=="wind"&&windE===true)
        userLocation.innerHTML="Based on your location, wind energy would be a good option";
    else if (pageIs()=="wind"&&windE===false)
        userLocation.innerHTML="Based on your location, wind energy would not be a good option";
    else if(pageIs()=="geo"&&geoE===true)
        userLocation.innerHTML="Based on your location, geothermal energy would be a good option";
    else if(pageIs()=="geo"&&geoE===false)
        userLocation.innerHTML="Based on your location, geothermal energy would not be a good option";
    else if(pageIs()=="hydro"&&hydroE===true)
        userLocation.innerHTML="Based on your location, hydroelectric energy would be a good option";
    else if(pageIs()=="hydro"&&hydroE===false)
        userLocation.innerHTML="Based on your location, hydroelectric energy would not be a good option";
}
```

Comment: `if(getSection()=="ba"||getSection()=="bb"||getSection()=="bc"|` Yikes, Why do you keep doing calculations over and over and over?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: The first thing that jumped out at me was missing semicolons in your onload method; you need semicolons after `setLat()` and the other methods.

Comment: Three things . . . (1) can you provide your HTML? (2) can you give us more information on what you mean by "I can't get a JavaScript location to be returned"?  Are you getting an error?  Is something not showing up?  Are you getting a value but it's not what you expected?  (3) Once you get your answer on this specific error, I'd recommend taking the working code to http://codereview.stackexchange.com to get more assistance on how to improve it . . . I think there are a lot of ways that you could make it more efficient, but that's a separate situation.   :)

Comment: Hi, first off thanks for taking the time to help, I really appreciate it. I know this probably isn't the best way to code, but it's the best I could do with a limited experience. Lastly, when I execute it, I get no errors, but nothing shows up in the div. Whenever I the variables after execution, it says everything is null or undefined, so I am just assuming the latitude and longitude never get assigned. I don't really think the HTML is very important because only two div's matter, the "location" div where the 'answer' is printed, and the empty div on each of 4 pages to say what page it is on